# Pandas DataFrame, smart apply of a complex function to groupby result

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with 3 columns of type `str` and `n` other columns of type `float64`.

I need to group rows by one of the three `str` columns and apply a function `myComplexFunc()` which will reduce `̀N  rows to one row.

`myComplexFunc()` take only rows of type `float64`.

This can be done with some for loops but it will not be efficient, So I tried to use the [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) of `pandas` but it seems that it runs the heavy code of `myComplexFunc()` twice!

To be more clear, here is a minimal example

**Let "df" be a dataFrame like this** :

```
df
>>
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one  0.406157  0.735223
1  bar    one  1.020493 -1.167256
2  foo    two -0.314192 -0.883087
3  bar  three  0.271705 -0.215049
4  foo    two  0.535290  0.185872
5  bar    two  0.178926 -0.459890
6  foo    one -1.939673 -0.523396
7  foo  three -2.125591 -0.689809
```

**myComplexFunc()**

```py
def myComplexFunc(rows):
  # Some transformations that will return 1 row
  result = some_transformations(rows)
  return result
```

**What I want :**

```py
# wanted apply is the name of the wanted method
df.groupby("A").wanted_apply(myComplexFunc)

>> 
    A    C            D
0  foo   new_c0_foo   new_d0_foo
1  bar   new_c0_bar   new_d0_bar
```

The column `B` have been removed because it's not of type `float64`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Flexible apply running given function twice in the first group is [documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply), see the warning at the bottom of that section.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter DataFrame by `dtype` by [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), but then need aggreagate by `Series` `df.A`:

```
def myComplexFunc(rows):
    return rows  + 10

df = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float64]).groupby([df.A]).apply(myComplexFunc)
print (df)
           C          D
0  10.406157  10.735223
1  11.020493   8.832744
2   9.685808   9.116913
3  10.271705   9.784951
4  10.535290  10.185872
5  10.178926   9.540110
6   8.060327   9.476604
7   7.874409   9.310191
```

because if use only `A`:

```
df = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float64]).groupby('A').apply(myComplexFunc)
```

get

> KeyError: 'A'

and it is right - all string columns are excluded (`A` and `B`).

```
print (df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float64]))
          C         D
0  0.406157  0.735223
1  1.020493 -1.167256
2 -0.314192 -0.883087
3  0.271705 -0.215049
4  0.535290  0.185872
5  0.178926 -0.459890
6 -1.939673 -0.523396
7 -2.125591 -0.689809
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the response, the problem is that `myComplexFunc()` will return one row for each set of rows grouped by the `̀choosen` crietria..

Comment: So do you need filter data in function as first step?